# How to split and replace strings in columns using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a tab-delim text file with only 4 columns as shown below:

```
GT:CN:CNL:CNP:CNQ:FT    .:2:a:b:c:PASS    .:2:c:b:a:PASS    .:2:d:c:a:FAIL
```

If the string  "FAIL" is found in a specific column starting from column2 to columnN (all the strings are separated by ":") then it would need to replace the second element in that column to "-1". Sample output is shown below:

```
GT:CN:CNL:CNP:CNQ:FT    .:2:a:b:c:PASS    .:2:c:b:a:PASS    .:-1:d:c:a:FAIL
```

Any help using awk?

Comment: Is the string FAIL always in the last ":" delimited part of the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/:FAIL$/) sub(/:[^:]+/,":-1",$i)} 1' file
GT:CN:CNL:CNP:CNQ:FT    .:2:a:b:c:PASS  .:2:c:b:a:PASS  .:-1:d:c:a:FAIL
```

Answer (score 2):

With gawk:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/[^:]*(:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]:FAIL)/,"-1\\1", "g" , $0)};1' File
```

with sed:

```
sed 's/[^:]*\(:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]:FAIL\)/-1\1/g' File
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to split in awk you can use `"split"`.

An example of it would be the following:

```
split(1,2,"3");
```

1. 1 is the string you want to split
2. 2 is the array you want to split it into
3. and 3 is the character that you want to be split on

e.g

```
string="hello:world"
result=`echo $string | awk '{ split($1,ARR,":"); printf("%s ",ARR[1]);}'`
```

In this case the result would be equal to `hello,` because we split the string to the **" : "** character and we printed the first half of the ARR, if we would print the second half (so printf("%s ",ARR[2])) of the ARR then it would be returned to result the "world".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU awk, you can take advantage of the `RT` feature<sup>1</sup> and split the records at tabs and newlines:

```
awk '$NF == "FAIL" { $2 = "-1"; } { printf "%s", $0 RT }' RS='[\t\n]' FS=':' infile
```

Output:

```
GT:CN:CNL:CNP:CNQ:FT    .:2:a:b:c:PASS  .:2:c:b:a:PASS  .:-1:d:c:a:FAIL
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The record separator that follows the current record.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are somewhat vague, but I'm pretty sure this does what you want with bog standard awk (no gnu-awk extensions):

```
awk '/FAIL/{$2=-1}1' ORS=\\t RS=\\t FS=: OFS=: input
```

Comment: It prints an extra tab at the end of the file, which you may want to trim in post processing (just pipe the output to `sed '$d'`).  Also, I'm taking some liberties; if column 1 matches 'FAIL' then this will modify the last column of the previous line, but I'm assuming that column 1 is always a fixed header.